# Как взломать зашифрованное сообщение

Tags: криптография, взлом, криптоаналитика

Интересует такой вопрос: у меня есть зашифрованное сообщение, я знаю даже как его расшифровать. Но вся проблема в том, что расшифровка происходит путем перебора, а перебор состоит из нескольких миллионов вариантов. Как мне из множества этих вариантов откинуть бессмысленные сообщения, простой набор букв, если известно, что исходное сообщение состоит только из букв русского языка.

Comment: всего миллионов ? не парьтесь, перебирайте. уже влоб бы давно расшифровали.

Comment: @eicto: насколько я понимаю, ТС так и делает, но ему нужен критерий остановки перебора. То есть надо отличить произвольный набор символов от осмысленного текста.

Answer (score 4):

Первая идея, самая хорошая: почитайте любую книгу по криптологии. Там описано в подробностях, и даже с исторической перспективой.

Вторая идея: убедитесь, что ваш перебор предоставит вам не *все возможные* тексты! Например, если у вас текст зашифрован [одноразовой лентой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0), его возможными расшифровками являются *все* в принципе возможные тексты данной длины, поэтому перебор не поможет.

Если открытый текст не был обработан специальным образом, в нём должны часто встречаться пробелы. В «случайном» наборе символов, которым часто бывает текст, расшифрованный неправильным ключом, пробелов должно быть недостаточно много. Если в расшифрованном тексте большинство слов длиннее 15 символов — считайте, что данный пароль не подходит.

Далее, вам пригодится словарь (поищите в интернете, их много).* В осмысленном тексте почти все слова (слово есть часть текста, состоящая из букв и внутренних дефисов) — из словаря, так что неправильные варианты должны быстро отсеиваться. Такое сработает, если пространство ключей небольшое по сравнению с длиной шифртекста, и можно рассчитывать, что среди ложных вариантов осмысленных текстов практически нет.

---

*Словари обычно сжаты таким образом, что различные словоформы представляются одной записью, так что вам придётся научиться разбирать внутренний формат. Возьмите, например, [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/). Есть и «распакованные» словари (например, [здесь](http://uinc.ru/forum/faqs/wordlist.shtml)), они больше, но с ними проще работать. Хотя качество разных словарей может отличаться, выбирайте сами.

Answer (score 0):

Мой путь в криптографию начался в детстве с рассказа Конан Дойля "Пляшущие человечки" и я до сих пор помню, что во всех классических книгах по занимательной криптографии рассказывается про частотный анализ встречающихся в тексте букв.

Если вы точно уверены, что у вас русский язык в тексте, то вы можете ориентироваться на то, что [самая частая буква](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) - это "о", "е", "а".

А значит, если вы получили текст и у вас кривая распределения частоты близка к эталонной - то вы с высокой степенью вероятности нашли текст.

Comment: Да-да, я знаю, что вопрос тридесятого года и есть ответ -- но просто попался на глаза в очереди проверок, не удержался чтобы не черкнуть свой ответ, он отличается от ответа VladD.